# Equivalent to a mips pseudo code

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

For reasons beyond my control, I am stuck with using an old mips toolchain.  When compiling some assembly code, I am getting the error  `Error: unknown pseudo-op: .reloc`
I would like to know what I can substitute for this to get my code compiling.

I have seen specific examples like [GNU assembler for MIPS: how to emit sync_* instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599564/gnu-assembler-for-mips-how-to-emit-sync-instructions)  and [translate mips pseudo instruction into machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214694/translate-mips-pseudo-instruction-into-machine-code). In the interest of learning to fish, rather than getting a fish, I would also like to know how I can go about translating this by myself. Is there a lookup reference to help?

The assembly code in question is:

```
    asm ( \
        ".text" "\n" \
        ".align 2" "\n" \
        ".set noreorder" "\n" \
        ".set nomacro" "\n" \
        ".set nomips16" "\n" \
        ".globl " SYMBOL_STRING(cti_##op) "\n" \
        ".ent " SYMBOL_STRING(cti_##op) "\n" \
        SYMBOL_STRING(cti_##op) ":" "\n" \
        ".set macro" "\n" \
        ".cpload $25" "\n" \
        "sw    $31," STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(THUNK_RETURN_ADDRESS_OFFSET) "($29)" "\n" \
        "la    $25," SYMBOL_STRING(JITStubThunked_##op) "\n" \
        ".set nomacro" "\n" \
        ".reloc 1f,R_MIPS_JALR," SYMBOL_STRING(JITStubThunked_##op) "\n" \
        "1: jalr $25" "\n" \
        "nop" "\n" \
        "lw    $31," STRINGIZE_VALUE_OF(THUNK_RETURN_ADDRESS_OFFSET) "($29)" "\n" \
        "jr    $31" "\n" \
        "nop" "\n" \
        ".set reorder" "\n" \
        ".set macro" "\n" \
        ".end " SYMBOL_STRING(cti_##op) "\n" \
        );
```

It can be seen online at https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit/source/0930236a6e8bef5c2b90f1522a06acf9dee9c15d:Source/JavaScriptCore/jit/JITStubs.cpp  starting line 1267

Comment: It would probably be helpful to show the snippet of assembler source code that triggers the error.

Comment: What's your binutils version? `.reloc` is a [valid directive at least from version 2.20](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Reloc.html) onwards.

Comment: @Jester  I am stuck with an old mips toolchain. Its version is 2.18

Comment: According to the [online manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/Reloc.html), 2.18 should also have `.reloc`. Strange.

Comment: @Jester I am sorry, I made a mistake. It is 2.16    mips-linux-ar --version
GNU ar 2.16.91.0.7 20060317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.reloc` pseudo-op instructs the assembler to emit a relocation in the binary output.  I'm not sure about the details.

I *believe* the intent is that the `jalr` instruction should jump to the subroutine called `JITStubThunked_<something>`.  Note how register `$25` is loaded with an address later used by `jalr`.

If the relocation isn't necessary for your context (I don't know what object formats your toolchain supports, etc), you can try to leave out the `.reloc` line entirely.  If the address fits, you can try to substitute the `la`+`jalr` with a single `jal " SYMBOL_STRING(JITStubThunked_##op) "`